How to disable or not be get accesse petstore page in nestjs/swagger?
While working on nestjs/swagger in api/index.html petstore Swagger is showing. I want to get disable or hide this page, or it should say api not found.
I tried with SwaggerUiOptions but could not get success. Also tried with other configuration option which is available in doc but could not got success.

You can try a middleware to stop that url.

html extension file is not getting working. Nest js seems can't track the html files.
